# Why can't I override statement_timeout in Dapper?

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, dapper, npgsql

I have postgresql statement timeout set globally like this:

```
ALTER ROLE user SET statement_timeout = '10s';
```

When I have a long running query I can override the timeout like this and it works fine from my DB IDE:

```
SET statement_timeout TO '0';
SELECT pg_sleep(20);
```

But when I execute the same thing from Dapper it throws the exception:

```
57014: canceling statement due to statement timeout
```

How can I make it work in Dapper?

Comment: Why not set the command timeout instead?

Comment: Because command timeout is a different thing (client side timeout vs server side timeout)

Comment: They refer to the same timeout, set through different mechanisms. Why set such a short global timeout to begin with? Do you have blocking or locking issues? This won't solve them. The server will still use resources to process these not-long queries and just discard the results. It's better to identify and fix the issues (missing indexes perhaps? long *transactions* that lead to increased conflicts?)

Comment: If the problem is blocking caused by long transactions the fix is to *not* use long transactions. Optimistic concurrency can improve scaleability by *several* orders of magnitude.

Comment: No, they don't refer to the same timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `statement_timeout` setting takes effect only starting from a next statement sent over network. My IDE sends multiple statements one by one while Dapper sends them all in one roundtrip. So to solve this I had to just split the thing into 2 `Execute` calls:

```
c.Execute("SET statement_timeout TO '0';");
c.Execute("SELECT pg_sleep(20);");
```

btw `SET` is applied to a session while `SET LOCAL` is applied to a transaction.